# Graphviz stable layout over multiple dot files

Tags: graphviz

I want to create a sequence of png files from graphviz to turn into an animation. The individual steps represent the turns of a game tournament and share a common structure. The dot files are output from a python program that creates the setup and not hand-written.

Unfortunately graphviz decides to lay them out differently making for an unnecessarily jumpy animation.

I have prepared two examples and linked to the source files and the resulting images. The structure of 11 tables with 11 players around each of them is the same in both files, but the engine layouts them differently.

Is there a way - short of specifying the layout myself - of making the two images render the same, save for shading of and labels for the nodes?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarianAldenhoevel/Misc/main/runde001.gv
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarianAldenhoevel/Misc/main/runde002.gv

Image rendered for round 1:
[image: runde001]

Image rendered for round 2:
[image: runde002]

Comment: Are you OK with using a pipeline of (multiple)  graphviz programs, instead of just fdp?

Answer (score 1):

(Converting videos from multiple graphs is a fun challenge.  This problem differs from a previous solution - https://forum.graphviz.org/t/stupid-dot-tricks-2-making-a-video/109)
There are no guarantees that one graph will be positioned exactly like another without explicitly setting the pos values (see https://www.graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithCoords)).  This is "doable" but takes some trial-and-error + programming.
However, making some small changes to your two samples and using a combination of Graphviz programs seemed to meet you goal.
The changes:

- remove the **layout=fdp** line (we are going to use **circo**)
- replace the **layout** line with

  - **node [fixedsize=true]**
  - **mindist=".3"** (you may want to tune this)

The pipeline:

```
for i in 1 2;do 
  f=runde00${i}.gv;F=`basename -s .gv $f`; 
  ccomps -x $f |circo | gvpack -m75 -array_it3 |neato -n2 -Tpng>$F.png; 
done
```

- We use **ccomps** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/ccomps.1.pdf) to convert one graph into 11 disconnected graphs
- **circo** (https://graphviz.org/pdf/dot.1.pdf) (poorly documented) to layout each of the (new) graphs into a circular layout
- **gvpack** (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) to take the (now eleven) graphs and create one combo graph in a 3 columns by X rows
- finally **neato** takes the text version of the combo graph and creates a png